# Is there any way to have 3 conditions in expression for datatable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datatable and have added expression for bit datatype column. So if i get 0 from DB, i replace that with "False" and for 1 i replace that with "True". Now my problem is, that field contains NULL too . I have used IIF, so my check is like:

```
Dim expression As String = String.Format("IIF({0}=0, {1}, {2})", colName, Boolean.FalseString, Boolean.TrueString)
```

So for NULL it is replacing it with True string, is there any way to handle NULLS and replace it with "" or blank

Comment: You simply nest one `IIF` inside the first, just like you would do if you were nesting a second `If` block in the `Else` of the first `If` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim expression As String = String.Format("IIF({0}=0, {1}, IIF({0}=1, {2}, ''))",
                                         colName,
                                         Boolean.FalseString,
                                         Boolean.TrueString)
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate for the 1st condition to be in the form of: `IIF([Column Name] Is Null`.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney, your expression worked for me. I was doing it some other way where the NULLS where replaced with False string.

Answer (score 0):

Cast result to nullable `Boolean` and call `.ToString()`.

```
var result = table.Field(Of Boolean?)("columnName").ToString()
```

From there [Boolean.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the value of this instance to its equivalent string
>   representation (either "True" or "False").

In case value is `DbNull` nullable of `Boolean` will not have a value and empty string will be returned.

From there [Nullable.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The text representation of the value of the current Nullable object
>   if the HasValue property is true, or an empty string ("") if the
>   HasValue property is false.

Example

```
Dim table As New DataTable()
table.Columns.Add("IsTest", GetType(Boolean))

Dim row0 = table.NewRow()
row0.SetField("IsTest", True)
table.Rows.Add(row0)

Dim row1 = table.NewRow()
row1.SetField("IsTest", DBNull.Value)
table.Rows.Add(row1)

Dim actual = table.AsEnumerable().
                   Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of Boolean?)("test")).
                   Select(Function(value) value.ToString()).
                   ToList()

Dim expected As New List(Of String) From { "True", "" }

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected) ' Pass
```

If you don't care about actual type of the column, you can simply call `ToString()` which will do similar thing.

```
row("IsTest").ToString()
```

It possible that you need do nothing if you displaying data in some controls, because `.ToString()` will be called by default in most of the cases.

Comment: Um, how does that fit into the `Expression` property of a `DataColumn`?

Comment: True, it will not. My answer is just an alternative to expression, which possibly will not fit OP's requirements. Sorry it was quick reaction to the expressions in `DataTable` ;)